# How can I create great documentation for my open source project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, open-source, documentation

After finishing an Open Source project you have to have a solid documentation website to let people understand how to use the code.

Examples of good documentations I have stumbled upon:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

http://vowsjs.org/

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

http://expressjs.com/

I have never created any kind of documentation on the web before and wish to hear some suggestions of tools to use to easily create as neat documentations as the above ones.

Also, does anyone use Drupal to create documentation?

Comment: Somebody voted to close this as "not a real question". I think it is a real question, but it is a duplicate. Also the title of the question - "Solid documentation website" - is not indicative of what's being asked. For real Q&A on this topic, try http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=generate+documentation , in particular, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001899/creating-great-api-documentation-tools-and-techniques . Also, you don't say who will consume the doc, or what it covers. Is it API documentation, doc for developer tools, doc for IT pros, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Great API Documentation: Tools and Techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001899/creating-great-api-documentation-tools-and-techniques)

Comment: @cheeso: The users who will consume the documentation are similar to the ones who will consume the linked documentations I provided as examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [pdoc](http://pdoc.org/), here's an [example](http://gf3.github.com/IRC-js/)